# React route v6 does not work in sprint boot app - whitelabel error 404

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot, react-router

I have been struggling to get my react app running over spring boot server. On running the spring server, I am able to see contents on `localhost:8080` however spring boot is not able to serve any static files `/about /login etc.` I get the `whitelabel Error Page 404` error .

**When I run the react app standalone on npm, I am able to route without any problem.**

I have followed the tutorials mentioned [here](https://dev.to/arpan_banerjee7/run-react-frontend-and-springboot-backend-on-the-same-port-and-package-them-as-a-single-artifact-14pa) but simplified it for my purposes.

The structure of my project looks like

```
src
   main
       java
           App.java
       resources
                application.propperties
       webapp
             src
                /components
                           NavMain.js
                /pages
                      AboutPage.js
                      WelcomePage.js
                /helpers
                app.js
```

This is what my App.JS looks like

```
<div>
  <NavMain />
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<WelcomePage />} />
      <Route exact path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

I am serving the react files in spring by copying files into static folder
pom.xml

```xml
<execution>
  <id>copy-resources</id>
  <!-- here the phase you need -->
  <phase>process-resources</phase>
  <goals>
    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
  </goals>
  <configuration>
    <outputDirectory>
     ${basedir}/target/classes/static
    </outputDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>
          src/main/webapp/build
        </directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

I tried

1. `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` but does not work
2. Add a `@controller` java file to route URL but did not work ([React-Router issues when serving React App with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413331/react-router-issues-when-serving-react-app-with-spring-boot))

Comment: dou you have any `index.html` page in your project ?

Comment: It gets build during react build. If I check my target/classes/static folder, there is a index.html

Comment: did you try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27383522/5521607 ? `registry.addViewController("/**").setViewName("forward:/index.html");`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is

```
package hype;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceResolverChain;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Redirects every page to index.html
 * Used to handle the router
 */
@Configuration
public class SinglePageAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
      .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
      .resourceChain(false)
      .addResolver(new PushStateResourceResolver());
  }

  private class PushStateResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {
    private Resource index = new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
    private List<String> handledExtensions = Arrays.asList("html", "js", "json", "csv", "css", "png", "svg", "eot", "ttf", "woff", "appcache", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "ico");
    private List<String> ignoredPaths = Arrays.asList("api");

    @Override
    public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
      return resolve(requestPath, locations);
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
      Resource resolvedResource = resolve(resourcePath, locations);
      if (resolvedResource == null) {
        return null;
      }
      try {
        return resolvedResource.getURL().toString();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return resolvedResource.getFilename();
      }
    }

    private Resource resolve(String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations) {
      if (isIgnored(requestPath)) {
        return null;
      }
      if (isHandled(requestPath)) {
        return locations.stream()
          .map(loc -> createRelative(loc, requestPath))
          .filter(resource -> resource != null && resource.exists())
          .findFirst()
          .orElseGet(null);
      }
      return index;
    }

    private Resource createRelative(Resource resource, String relativePath) {
      try {
        return resource.createRelative(relativePath);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    private boolean isIgnored(String path) {
      return ignoredPaths.contains(path);
    }

    private boolean isHandled(String path) {
      String extension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(path);
      return handledExtensions.stream().anyMatch(ext -> ext.equals(extension));
    }
  }
}
```